# How to run Padrino project in production mode?

Tags: ruby, environment, production, padrino

I am making a backend api using Padrino ruby framework.
And I would like to know how to run project on production mode.
Now I run the server with this command.

```
padrino s
```

It is running on development mode.
I tried this one.

```
padrino s RACK_ENV='production'
```

but it make erros.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag to specify environment in padrino is `-e`. So the command would be:

`padrino start -e production`

or

`RACK_ENV=production padrino s`

Notice how in your case `RACK_ENV='production'` has quotes around `'production'`. You should remove them and try.

From the [padrino documentation](http://padrinorb.com/guides/features/development-commands/), other possible combinations are:

```
# starts the app server (non-daemonized)
$ padrino start
# starts the app server (daemonized) with given port, environment and adapter
$ padrino start -d -p 3000 -e development -a thin

# Stops a daemonized app server
$ padrino stop

# Bootup the Padrino console (irb)
$ padrino console

# Run/List tasks
$ padrino rake

# Run piece of code in the context of Padrino (with given environment)
$ padrino runner 'puts Padrino.env' -e development

# Run Ruby file in the context of Padrino
$ padrino r script/my_script.rb
```